# android ndk path stl library to linker twice

Tags: android, linker, android-ndk, ld

In my Application.mk there is line:
APP_STL := gnustl_static

But ndk-build provides to linker path to libgnustl_static right after my module object file in such way:

g++ app.o /android-ndk/..some..folders/libgnustl_static.a (from here my LOCAL_LDFLAGS) -L../external_lib -Bstatic -la1

But liba1 is static library that wants implementation of stl. Thus I shoud pass libgnustl_static.a ageter -la1. How to do this in a right beautiful way without full path /android-ndk/..some..folders/libgnustl_static.a ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up by specifying my liba1 as PREBUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY (see Android.mk documentation)